# android: json exception

Tags: android, json

I am getting some response from server side which i need to parse but not by names i.e. this the response changes time to time.

```
  type = "data_updates";
        updates =             {
            "offers_all" =                 {
                columns =                     (
                    "record_id",
                    "display_name",
                    "sorting_name",
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    "custom_ad_banner_resource_id",
                    description,
                    "website_url",
                    "phone_number",
                    hours,
                    advertiser,
                    "street_address",
                    "offer_id",
                    "offer_section",
                    "start_date",
                    "end_date",
                    "custom_leaf_template",
                    "location_area"
                );
                data =                     (
                                            (
                        "09834-234234",
                        "The Example Offer",
                        "example offer, the",
                        "-122.234234",
                        "31.2342343",
                        "",
                        "An Example of an Offer.",
                        "http=>//freeruntech.com/",
                        "1.707.555.1212",
                        "10am - 5pm",
                        Yes,
                        "3145 State Street,\nCalistoga, CA, 94500",
                        "",
                        "",
                        "2011-08-24",
                        "2011-12-31",
                        "",
                        Napa
                    )}
```

I have used the following code for getting the main jsonobjects

```
if (show.get("type").equals("data_updates")) 
{   
    JSONObject data_updates = show.getJSONObject("updates");

    JSONArray array_containing_values= new JSONArray();
    JSONArray data_updates_values=data_updates.names();

    System.out.println(data_updates_values);
    for(int m=0; m<data_updates_values.length(); m++)
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject((String) data_updates_values.get(m));
        JSONArray names = new JSONArray();
        names= obj.toJSONArray(names);                  
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}
```

But it is giving me exception

```
   Value events of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

How shall i get the values of data and columns `JSonobjects`.

Can anyone help me over this?

thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like valid JSON. Are you sure you get JSON in response?

Comment: @Nikita Actually I have just written a part of it here the response is very large actually.

Comment: Perhaps you could validate your response using http://jsonlint.com/ just to be sure.

Comment: JSON doesn't have parentheses '()' in it's notation http://www.json.org/

Comment: How are you getting your response?

Comment: @Aditya To be sure the response is in a valid JSON format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing like this?

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // Read the content stream
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
                }

                // convert content stream to a String
                String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.v(null, "resultString "+resultString);
                instream.close();


                // Transform the String into a JSONObject
                if(resultString!=null){
                    jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

                }

            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<jsonobject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");
```

are you getting the response like this?

if so. here resultstring will be 'show' try

```
JSONObject jsshow = new JSONObject(show)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a valid json that is the problem. in json = are replaced by : , and array of values start with [ and end with ], there is not ; in json. look at the following link..

http://www.json.org/